# Find the inverse image of this function

Tags: functions

> A function is defined by this formula: 
>  $$f:\mathbb N \times
>  \mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to \mathbb N \times \mathcal P(\mathbb N) \\
>  f(x,y) = \{\min(\{x\} \cup y), y \setminus \{x\} \}$$ Find
>   $$f^{-1}[\{0\} \times \mathcal P(\mathbb N)]$$

As for me, this question is not clear - if I understand correctly, I need to find all possible pairs $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = (0, n)$ where $n \subseteq \mathbb N$. Therefore, I can think of two possibilities: 

a) Zero comes from the first coordinate 
b) Zero comes from the second coordinate or from both of them at the same time 
 
a) Answer: $$\{(0, n) \mid n\subseteq \mathbb N\}$$ 
b) Answer: 
$$\{(m,n) \mid m\in\mathbb N \land n\subseteq \mathbb N \land 0 \in n \}$$
Now, it's enough to take the sum of these two sets and we are done. 

Is this the correct solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but write it down properly, the result has to be a subset of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$:

\begin{aligned}
f^{-1}(\{0\} \times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})) &= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) : (\min(\{x\}\cup y),y\setminus\{x\}) \in \{0\}\times\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\}\\
&=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) : \min(\{x\}\cup y) = 0\}\\
&=\left(\{0\} \times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\right) \cup \left(\mathbb{N} \times \mathcal{A}\right)
\end{aligned}

where $\mathcal{A}:=\{ B \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) : \{0\} \in B)$. Note that $y\setminus\{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ in any case, that gives you the second equality.